# Baking an edge mask image problem

Tags: edges, texture-baking, baking, bevel

I am using cycles to make an edge mask using a node group (screenshots below). I baked this mask on to a 2048*2048 black square image. I save the image. I apply the image texture to the object, resulting in the pictured stretched edges. I tried it with more complex shapes also, which messes it up even more. I imagine what is happening is that the 2d image cannot distinguish the inset face as a face, and treats the entire axis as an edge, how then do I fix it and make it work for complex shapes? Blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/8e73d73390d54cada30bf7a6a55e6f52

Really really appreciate a solution. I have been working in cycles as a work around, but for design purposes it really slows me down.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the UVs you extruded inwards. The other faces baked normally because they existed for the original cube which came with those UVs.

Comment: I am quite a noob, sorry. You are right. I selected the cube, selected everything and did a smart UV project, I baked the mask again, and the resulting image worked!

Comment: Smart UV is a quick solution, but I recommend learning more about UVing. Cheers. You can click the checkmark on the left of an answer to mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: What would be a better / efficient / more sophisticated solution? Or do you have a guide / video that perhaps tells me about it? Thanks.

Comment: The main goals for this model is to fill as much of your texture as possible, keep uvs straight in line with the image's pixels whhile minimizing distortion, have enough space between islands to prevent bleeding, all without overdoing the number of seams. There are a lot of rules that weigh in. I don't know that I can link videos and there aren't a lot that I know of that concisely break it down. I hope to make a video that does that in the future on my yt channel.

Comment: Sure, it's a complex subject :D thanks anyway, peace.

Answer (score 0):

I received a fix elsewhere, as follows:

Edit mode for the object in question:

Select all (A) -
Select U or Right click -> Unwrap -
Smart UV Project -> Use default values -> OK -
Bake the texture